# Fastest data structures to use when parsing HTML

Tags: java, data-structures

So I'm looking at a web page and parsing HTML to extract image links. These links could be as less as 25 and can got up to 500+. The images are then downloaded to a folder.
I think that an efficient way of doing this is, instead of having a while loop that extracts data and writes the file one by one, is to have a while loop extract data from the HTML and store the links as an object then using a data structure to hold these objects. Then I'll looop through the data structure performing the write file operations
Is this way of approach better than the other one? What would be 'good practice' approach for this problem and what would be the most efficient/fastest data structure for this task ? I was thinking a Set or an AraryList ?

Comment: Please edit your question, I am having difficulty understanding what you are saying.

Comment: This would probably do better on [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com/), but first, consider mentioning why performance is even a consideration. Simple parsing is not, in general, especially time-sensitive.

Comment: If all you're talking about is extracting the links from the HTML text, then you're really focusing on the wrong problem. This won't be your performance bottleneck.

Comment: Done.well I think for code review you need a full code available

Comment: @chrylis It's extracting and downloading 500+ image

Comment: Extract each link, store them either as `String` or `URL`, use a POJO to associate it with a `File`, place this into an `ExecutorService` of some kind...

Comment: *Why* do you think it would be more efficient? The network will dominate, not your processing, but all you're accomplishing is *adding* processing. Unless you use threads, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @EJP could you explain more the threads thing ?I read about them but I don't think I completely understand them. Why would running a separate thread be faster at all ? Thanks